# Azure Runbook check status

Tags: azure-automation, azure-runbook

There is an Azure Automation runbook, which runs Powershell script below. It checks if runbook has running jobs already, and if no, execute some script.

The problem:

If I run it on "Test Pane" it works fine, but once I run via schedule or start as a job, it always exists with an output job is running.
There are no jobs running and running code from my laptop it shows not running as well.
Why it goes well on a Runbook test pane, but fails on normal run?

```
param (
[string]$runbook = "test-rb",
[string]$rgName = "test-rg",
[string]$aaName = "test-aa"
)

$jobs = Get-AzAutomationJob -ResourceGroupName $rgName -AutomationAccountName $aaName -RunbookName $runbook
#$Jobs.status

# Check to see if it is already running

if (($jobs.status -contains "Running") -Or ($jobs.Status -eq "New"))
{   
    Write-Output "Runbook execution is stopped [$runbook] - there is another job currently running."
    exit 1
} 
else
{
    Write-Output "Proceed with runbook execution [$runbook]  - there are no interfering jobs running."
}

try {
    ....my script
}
catch {
    ....something something
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Becasue when you run the job, it will get itself as a `Running` job via the command `Get-AzAutomationJob`, add the `Write-Output $jobs` in your script, see the screenshot below, notice the `Id` and the `JobId` is the same.

[image]

To solve the issue, you could use `$jobs = $jobs[1..($jobs.Length-1)]`, it will exclude itself, then the script will work fine.

**My sample**:

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    "Logging in to Azure..."
    $null = Add-AzAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}
$jobs = Get-AzAutomationJob -ResourceGroupName <resourcegroup-name> -AutomationAccountName joyauto1 -RunbookName test1
$jobs = $jobs[1..($jobs.Length-1)]
if (($jobs.status -contains "Running") -Or ($jobs.Status -eq "New"))
{   
    Write-Output "Runbook execution is stopped [] - there is another job currently running."
    exit 1
} 
else
{
    Write-Output "Proceed with runbook execution []  - there are no interfering jobs running."
}
```

[image]